# "I agree that technology itself has changed" Why do they have to put "itself"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I think that this sentence can be understood without put "itself".
I think it's used to emphasize "Technology", isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... technology itself has changed.

That assertion with **itself** is contextual. It alludes to an earlier statement in the conversation where the discussion was about change occasioned by technology (or something along those lines) and states that technology has not only caused change but has itself changed.  It brought change and it too has changed.  **Itself** is a way to focus attention on the preceding noun in isolation, as its own context.

> We were talking about how work in an office had changed as a result of technology,  but then we got to talking about how the technology itself had changed—typewriters, telegraph, telephones, carbon paper, photocopiers, desk calculators, computers, fax, email, and so on.

Comment: That means Technology was a cause of change and it was changing too, Right?

Comment: @Martuaii: I do not know what you are referring to with "that".

Comment: I mean if I didn't miss understand what you tried to describe me, "Itself" will express either technology is the cause of change and it is changing, Right?
*sorry for my grammar*

Comment: The pronoun **itself** (and "yourself" *et al*) is a way of emphasizing and focusing on the noun it refers to.    *Not only did technology change the way people worked, technology itself had changed.*  Technology was not only a bringer of change but a thing which had undergone change.